# GCloud Function with service account does not have permissions to use the same service account

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I have a GCloud Function with an attached service account "a@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com".
I want to use the function to create a cloud task, but I am receiving this error

```
The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission "iam.serviceAccounts.actAs" for the resource "a@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" (or the resource may not exist).
```

Why does this happen? Should it not need to have the "actAs" permissions for itself?

Using terraform, I attempted to add that role to the service account, I get
`Error 400: Role roles/serviceAccounts.actAs is not supported for this resource.`

I also don't see the option in the IAM UI